# Serving certificate only for some traffic on port 443 with HAProxy

Tags: ssl, haproxy

I've purchased a wildcard certificate (say, *.example.com).

I want to serve that using HAProxy, which is no issue. However, I don't know how to tell HAProxy not to serve certificates for anything that doesn't match *.example.com as the host.

These are being served by another service (using Let's Encrypt) which I'd like to redirect traffic to.

Comment: Certificates are not served but they are sent by the server as part of a TLS handshake. The TLS handshake is initiated by the client. Once the client starts with a TLS handshake HAProxy must somehow reply. A proper response would be to continue with the TLS handshake which involves sending some certificates. An alternative reaction would be to just close the connection which will result in an error in the client. So far you only state that it should not provide the specific certificate. But you don't say what it should do instead.

Comment: Also note that the server name is commonly send as SNI extension inside the ClienHello (start of TLS handshake). But, there might be some clients which don't do this (only few, for example all browsers use SNI) which means that HAProxy will not know what hostname the client want to reach. This will be likely contained in the HTTP dialog later, but these requires a successful TLS handshake first and thus the sending of the expected certificate. If you want to deal with such clients you also need to specify how this specific case should be handled.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @SteffenUllrich. I want another service to serve the certificate not HAProxy for certain hosts. I've got a backend defined in the HAProxy and want to use it for specific hosts that HAProxy shouldn't hanlde the TLS handshake for.

Comment: [Mixing TLS termination and SNI passthrough in one haproxy configuration](https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/mixing-tls-termination-and-sni-passthrough-in-one-haproxy-configuration/1747) or [Pass-through SSL with HAProxy and vhosts on same IP](https://serverfault.com/questions/949576/pass-through-ssl-with-haproxy-and-vhosts-on-same-ip) might help you.

Answer (score 2):

### Problem

The problem I had was I wanted to HAProxy to handle the SSL/TLS handshake for a domain and any of its subdomains (I bought a wildcard certificate).

Anything that didn't match that domain, I wanted to generate SSL certificates for them through Let's Encrypt using [Greenlock](https://git.rootprojects.org/root/greenlock.js) and I also needed Greenlock to handle the SSL/TLS handshake.

### Solution

In HAProxy, we bind to port 80 and 443 to listen to traffic on both ports.

On port 80, we:

- redirect to HTTPS protocol, if the request is not SSL and the request path doesn't begin with `/.well-known/acme`
- use greenlock backend, if host in the request header doesn't match our wildcard domain

```
frontend http-in
    acl acme_challenge path_beg /.well-known/acme
        acl is_wildcard_domain hdr_end(Host) example.com
        bind *:80

        redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc } !acme_challenge
        use_backend greenlock_http if !is_wildcard_domain acme_challenge
```

For port 443, we:

- first use tcp mode since we don't want to handle SSL handshake at this point
- setup logging so we can see `req.ssl_sni` which normally contains the
  name of the host the client tries to connect (i.e. your domain)
- use greenlock_https backend if the host name doesn't match wildcard domain
- or use https-back backend as the fallback (i.e. use this if host matches wildcard domain)

```
frontend https-in
        bind *:443
        mode tcp

        tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
        tcp-request content capture req.ssl_sni len 40
        log-format "%ci:%cp [%t] %ft %b/%s %Tw/%Tc/%Tt %B %ts %ac/%fc/%bc/%sc/%rc %sq/%bq ssl_sni: %[capture.req.hdr(0)]"

        tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }
        acl is_wildcard_domain req.ssl_sni -m end "${WILDCARD_DOMAIN}"

        use_backend greenlock_https if !is_wildcard_domain
        default_backend https-back
```

Where it gets interesting is the `https-back` backend:

- it simply forwards the request to this address `unix@/var/run/haproxy.sock`

```
backend https-back
    mode tcp
    server https-front unix@/var/run/haproxy.sock send-proxy-v2
```

Who's listening on that address? It's a frontend that serves the wildcard certificate:

```
frontend https-front
    bind   unix@/var/run/haproxy.sock ssl crt /etc/haproxy/paid_certs/exapmle.com.crt accept-proxy
    mode   http
    option forwardfor
    reqdel X-Forwarded-Proto
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https if { ssl_fc }

    default_backend elb
```

For completeness, here are all the frontend and backends:

```
frontend http-in
frontend http-in
        acl acme_challenge path_beg /.well-known/acme
        acl is_wildcard_domain hdr_end(Host) example.com
        bind *:80

        redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc } !acme_challenge
        use_backend greenlock_http if !is_wildcard_domain acme_challenge

frontend https-in
        bind *:443
        mode tcp

        tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
        tcp-request content capture req.ssl_sni len 40
        log-format "%ci:%cp [%t] %ft %b/%s %Tw/%Tc/%Tt %B %ts %ac/%fc/%bc/%sc/%rc %sq/%bq ssl_sni: %[capture.req.hdr(0)]"

        tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }
        acl is_wildcard_domain req.ssl_sni -m end example.com

        use_backend greenlock_https if !is_wildcard_domain
        default_backend https-back

backend greenlock_http
        server greenlock greenlock:80 
        cookie webserver insert indirect nocache

backend greenlock_https
        mode tcp
        server greenlock greenlock:443

backend https-back
        mode tcp
        server https-front unix@/var/run/haproxy.sock send-proxy-v2

frontend https-front
        bind   unix@/var/run/haproxy.sock ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/example.com accept-proxy
        mode   http
        option forwardfor
        reqdel X-Forwarded-Proto
        reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https if { ssl_fc }

        default_backend elb

backend elb
        mode http
        server elb ${ELB_HOST}
        balance roundrobin     #balance type
        option forwardfor
        cookie webserver insert indirect nocache
```